# Oracle Spatial - spatial index on time-varying data

Tags: oracle, indexing, geospatial, spatial, database-partitioning

I am trying to design a datamodel on geodetic data which performs decently as the data grow over time. However all ideas I got have hit a couple of limitations by Oracle.

These are the requirements:

- the data to store are 2-dimensional points with latitude and longitude (being able to handle any geometry would be a plus).
- New data are added on a monthly basis. This conceptually updates the position of the points, deletes old points or creates new ones. New data for new time-instants come in batches, and as such are conceptually ordered and labelled. Say: `t1`, `t3`, `t4`. (it is not a form of asset tracking, it is more of an evolving snapshot of data).
- SELECTs on current or historical data must execute in real time (e.g. to be be depicted on an interactive map). SELECT statements will query data like "return all points belonging to a given region, as of t3", expecting to return an image of the initial data with the changes applied at times `t1`, `t3`
- It is not known in advance what proportion of the original points are left unchanged. So for instance 100% of the points might be altered when receiving a new batch of data, or just 0%.

The data are conceptually tuples of `(t, geometry)`, and the main problem is that you cannot create a spatial index on `t and geometry`, but only on `geometry`.
Overall, **the point is that indexing geographical data that are conceptually "sliced", by another column, is apparently not supported**.

By the way, in spite of appearance, saving all data as complete snapshots, or saving the changes as incremental deltas is not really the point of the whole matter, and makes no real difference.

Below are my failed attempts to solve the problem. If anyone has good ideas on how to efficiently model the data, just skip the remainder of this post  (otherwise I would appreciate if one could elaborate on the options I have tried so far.)

### First unsuccessful attempt - multi-column spatial index

I would save complete "snapshots" of the data at times `t1,t3,t4`, and **the data would be identified by two columns, the geometry and an identifier of the slice of data**:

`create table geocoded_data (
  geom SDO_GEOMETRY,
  snapshot_id number(5,0)
);`

Of course, geometries require a spatial index to efficiently be operated on, and the obvious choice would have been a two-columns index. This is where the idea fails, because **multi-column index cannot be spatially indexed** (such as a spatial one):

`CREATE INDEX my_index ON geocoded_data(snapshot_id, geom)
  INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index;
SQL Error: ORA-29851: "cannot build a domain index on more than one column"`

### Second unsuccessful attempt - adding another dimension to the geometries

Another option would be to **model the column `snapshot_id` as a third dimension** embedded in the `geom` field. However unless documented somewhere, one cannot assume that the resulting index will work properly on such a data structure.
After all, the third-dimension would be just a marker, with no geometrical significance, so potentially hindering the performance of the index.

This option would be conceptually similar to using LSR (Linear Referencing Systems) on points.
And in fact It might be no coincidence that the [docs about LSR indexing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/GUID-CA7D44D7-CB40-4C33-9345-2C84F43CF8CA.htm#SPATL760) state:

> Do not include the measure dimension in a spatial index, because this causes additional processing overhead and produces no benefit

### Third unsuccessful attempt - interval partitioning

A third way to go would be **partitioning the data according to the column `snapshot_id`, and creating a *local* spatial index**. In this case, hopefully, a partition elimination would help using the relevant portion of the spatial index, disregarding the data in other snapshots.
The partition would be an "interval partition" (a new partition would be nicely and automatically created upon receiving a new batch of data). However this is what I get when I try to create a spatial index on an interval-partitioned table:

`SQL Error: ORA-14762: "Domain index creation on interval partitioned tables is not permitted"`

That's true, intended and documented: partitions are generally ok except that ***interval* partitions are not supported by spatial indexes**. Indeed [Using Partitioned Spatial Indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_index_query.htm#SPATL586) explicitly says:

> Only range partitioning is supported on the underlying table. All other kinds of partitioning are not currently supported for partitioned spatial indexes.

So, I should make do with a range partition. However I'd rather exclude this option because it would entail in some amount of "system" maintenance (creating new partitions manually, or as part of the application logic, which would be awkward).
Ideally I wanted a new partition for each snapshot, and I'd like to have the partition created automatically whenever a new snapshot is introduced.

### Fourth unsuccessful attempt - representing the data in an incremental fashion

The last option, which is the most CPU intensive, would persist the initial snapshot of data, while saving the new batches in form of deltas.
However, as a matter of fact, this wouldn't address the fundamental issue at the hearth of the problem (unability to spatially index geometries discriminated by the content of another column).

For instance, when the application had to reconstruct the content of a given portion of the map up to `t2`, it would have to retrieve all data that are related to that map portion, up to the deltas belonging to `t2`.

Unfortunately the spatial would fetch all deltas in the relevant portion of the map, including those that are irrelevant because were added later than `t2`. For instance the index would identify:

- **point A**, OK: part of the initial snapshot
- **point B**, OK: was added on the same map portion by `t2`
- **point C, D, E, F**: KO!... were added to the same map portion but by a later **t3**, so will be excluded only by a predicate, not by the index.

On the other hand, even if the index returned only the records we need, this wouldn't be sustainable, because changes would add up over time and the cost of returning the current image after, say, 10 years of changes might be outrageous (to get the right image, one should combine all deltas that were introduced after the initial snapshot).